# Статистика активности пользователя

Tags: node.js, mysql

Необходимо реализовать статистику активности пользователя (Node.js + MySQL), т.е сколько пользователь был в игре онлайн за весь день.

Собственно, интересует структура БД, чтобы потом можно было вывести статистику с помощью [morris](http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js).

Comment: расскажите чуть более детально, статистика и активность очень разной бывает.

Answer (score 1):

База данных в вашем случае должна решать две совершенно разные задачи. С одной стороны, нужно вести статистику (*писать данные*), с другой стороны, нужно выводить статистику (*читать данные*). Загвоздка в том, что данные будут накапливаться и просчитывать статистику будет всё сложнее и сложнее. Отсюда потребность создать разные таблицы (на первое время - *см. ниже*) для хранения времени в игре. В одной будем хранить идентификатор пользователя и временные метки начала/конца сессии. Во второй - сводную информацию о времени в игре по дням.

Иными словами, смысл в том, чтобы хранить в одном месте факты, а в другом - результаты расчетов:

```
-- Сессии пользователей
CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `id_user` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `session_start` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `session_end` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM;

-- Статистика по дням
CREATE TABLE `statistics` (
    `id_user` INT NOT NULL,
    `period` DATE NOT NULL,
    `total` INT(0) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_user`, `period`)
) ENGINE = MYISAM;
```

Важный момент. Время начала сессии база отловит сама, а вот время окончания нужно дописать. Либо хранить информацию о начале/конце игровой сессии где-то не в БД, а при окончании сессии, сразу писать обе временные метки. Это позволит обойтись без апдейтов, что хорошо для производительности.

Выше я сказал про создание таблиц, но можно сразу озаботиться партициями.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `play_time` (
 `user_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
 `start` DATETIME ,
 `end` DATETIME ,
KEY  `user_id` (  `user_id` )
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8
```